# Two jars having same package name, same class name and same method name

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, jar, classloader

I am facing this problem in spring boot application where I am using Two jars. And in those jars there are two classes with the same package name and same class name and one  method with the same name . Problem occurs when class loader loads the class from different jar and tries to call this method, If jar A is loaded first then method is called and everything works fine , But if  jar B is called first then, NOSUCHMETHODERROR exception is thrown at runtime. Can you please help to fix this. Is there a way by which I can force the classloader to load a particular jar first, always in Spring boot app, Or probably any other fix for this.

NOTE: I am using JAVA 8 and I don't have access to the source code of these jar files.

Comment: why would you have two completely identical paths? that makes no sense.

Comment: That is code written by some one else , and the source code is not available. That is why :)

Comment: "code written by someone else", don't use it. I don't see any decent way to do this. What you can do (I wouldn't) is to create two new libraries, in one you have your class extending the class from jar A, in the other the one of jar B. That might help

Comment: You don’t need the source code to remove a jar file from the class path or to remove a `.class` entry from a jar file. Besides that, in case of the standard `URLClassLoader`, the class path entries are searched in the specified order.

Comment: There are cases where you cant get around this problem. In my produce(dbWatch) we have to connect to all versions of a given database. So we need to support many oracle drivers at the same time. They contain the same classes in different versions.

Comment: You need to load the different jars in seperate classloaders. This is not at all dificult do do in code. Basically new UrlClassLoader and some reflection to create your classes.

Comment: Sounds like you should just get rid of jar B entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading those jars as a dependency you could exclude it from Maven via

```
<exclusions>
   <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.XXXX</groupId>
        <artifactId>jar1-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```